# Memoir: Change chapter name mid document

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, memoir, chapters

I would like to redefine the chapter name in the middle of the document.
This change should affect the table of contents, page headers and chapter titles in the document. I guess I want something similar to an appendix, but slightly different.

```
\chapter{title 1}
foo
\CHANGECHAPTERNAME{NewChapterName}
\chapter{title 2}
bar
\appendix
\chapter{title 3}
blabla
```

should yield something like: (never mind the formatting, I'm just interested in changing the name)

> 

### *Table of Contents:*

> - Chapter 1:  *title1*
> - NewChapterName 1: *title2*
> - Appendix A: *title3*
>
> ---

### *Body:*

> **Chapter 1:  title1**
>
> foo
>
> **NewChapterName 1: title2**
>
> bar
>
> **Appendix A: title3**
>
> blabla

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post a full minimal example instead of sniplet code. That makes it a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. In the future please remember to add a full minimal example. `memoir` does not add the `Chapter` prefix in the toc by default, so that detail is relevant to the MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}
\newcommand\newchaptername{NewChapterName}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*


\chapter{title 1}
foo

% change the chaptername from now on
\renewcommand\chaptername{\newchaptername}
% insert the change into the toc file
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchaptername{\newchaptername~}}

\chapter{title 2}

\kant


\appendix
\chapter{title 3}
blabla


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! Sorry for not adding a MWE.